# two consecutive uppercase REST controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi guys I hope someone can help me, I'm using laravel 4 and I have a REST controller like this

```
Route::controller('example', 'SomeClass');



class SomeClass extends BaseController {

public function getThisIsATest() {
    return 'Hello World';
}

}
```

but when I try to enter the URI *localhost/example/this-is-a-test*

I get a **'Controller method not found.**'

I'm thinking it's because the two consecutive uppercase letters in the '**getThisIsATest**'

Does someone know how to fix this issue??

Comment: So , how can I define it properly in order to get the response in the URI: localhost/example/this-is-a-test??

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need your function name to be so set in stone? I would think that if the route doesn't work because of a bad function name, you would change the function name to fix it. Hopefully you can figure this out without changing the name, but I see a complicated solution to simple problem and just wonder **why**?

Comment: Yeah @TimLewis I know it's kinda silly of my part trying to archive this by all the means, but the real reason what I'm asking this is because all my site is in spanish, so my real route is `localhost/ejemplo/terminos-y-condiciones` in english that will be `terms and conditions`, so now you now if I just cut the `y` I'll ended up having just `terms conditions`

Comment: but if that the only way to do it, so let it be jejeje :P

Comment: Now that makes a lot more sense. What I would recommend is use a combination of `Route::controller()` and `Route::get()` where the latter would be used for any routes that can't be caught by `Route::controller()`. That way, you wouldn't have to define a route for every action, only the ones that can't work, like `terminos-y-condiciones` or... I don't know Spanish, but you get the idea :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways (without changing the URL)...

### 1. Use an additional route

Add an implicit route for the URL *before* the controller route:

```
Route::get('example/this-is-a-test', 'SomeClass@getThisIsATest');
Route::controller('example', 'SomeClass');
```

### 2. Change your method name to snake_case

You can change the method name in your controller to snake case and everything will work as excepted. (It doesn't look very pretty though)

```
public function get_this_is_a_test() {
    return 'Hello World';
}
```

Actually it even works to only write the "problematic" part in snake case: `getThisIsA_test`. However this looks even more weird ;)

Comment: jajajajaja :P
I didn't knew that you can put a snake_case in you method to do that.
Although it look ugly I will stick with the 2nd way.

Comment: Laravel internally converts every method name of the controller to snake_case when transforming it into an URI that's the reason why this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::resource('example/this-is-a-test', 'SomeClassController@getThisIsATest');
```

OR:

```
Route::get('example/this-is-a-test', 'SomeClassController@getThisIsATest');
```

See, if that solves your problem & Do visit [Laravel Controller Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers) for more information

Add `{{ URL::to('example/this-is-a-test'); }}` and you're good to go

Comment: When you just put ClassName, laravel expects these byfeault functions: index, create, show, store, edit, update, destroy

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to solve the problem, but the thing is, Is there a way to do it in a REST or IMPLICIT controller way??

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/routes.php` try defining your route as follows:

```
Route::controller("example", "testController");
```

And rename your controller class to

```
class testController extends BaseController {

  public function index(){
    // Just have it here to be safe.
  } 
  public function getTest() {
    return 'Hello World';
  }
}
```

Now try navigating to `localhost/example/test`. Let me know if that works, I've never used `Route::controller()` before, so it's new to me as well.

**Edit**

As the above doesn't work for this example, try navigating to `localhost/example/this-is-atest` without changing your controller/route.

Comment: Yes that solve the problem, unfortunately I do really need the URI to be `localhost/example/this-is-a-test`

Comment: So in order to archive this I need to put two consecutive uppercase letters in the defining function, but apparently that's an issue for laravel

Comment: See my edit. It's ugly, but (from what I can see) the only way to get Laravel to handle that function name.

Comment: Yes if I navigate to `localhost/example/this-is-atest` it works.

It's sad that you can't put two uppercase letters next to each other :(

Comment: Yeah, that is a very strange issue you found :P.